# ArtistAnimation, matplotlib: making animation from a set of images

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am relatively new to python. 
I would like to make an animated heatmap of a 34x34 matrix through time. I am trying to do it using matplotlib. `data` is a 3d array 34x34x100.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(34,34))
img_collection=[]

for t in range(0,100):
    frame = plt.imshow(data[:,:,t], interpolation='nearest', shape=(34,34))
    img_collection.append([frame])

animation = matplotlib.animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, img_collection, interval=200)
animation.save('path/to/file.mp4', fps=3)
```

Unfortunately the file `.mp4` created is totally black.
I would be very grateful for any advice or help, thank you!

Comment: You need to tell the save method to use a certain writer, probably a ffmpeg writer for `.mp4`. I think there are enough questions around that show how to do that.